# Why can't I disable stack protection?

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow, exploit

The OS I am currently using is 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 with its gcc version being 4.8.4.

I wrote a simple program as shown below to do some testings related to buffer overflow, and somehow I found that I could not overflow a local character string properly.

```
/*test.c*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[4];
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="123456789012345'; 

    /* This is the maximum length the string
     can be, which is 16 bytes including the null character at the end, and 
    any strings that are longer than this would result in a segmentation fault */

    bof(str);
}
```

This program was compiled with command

```
gcc -o test -fno-stack-protector test.c
```

so that supposedly stack protection should have been disabled.

Based on my observation, any strings that were less than or equal to 16 characters in length (including the null character) would be okay; otherwise, it would cause a segmentation fault.

Any thoughts why and how could I make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Accessing an array out-out-bounds is **undefined behaviour** as off the C standard. Think about the meaning of the word "**undefined**".

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I do understand that access out-of-bound addresses is undefined behavior, or at least I think I do. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is not out-of-bound addresses essentially some data-storing memory chunks that can be accesses and modified? So if I have turned stack protection, which theoretically would enable me to play with those out-of-bound addresses, and if I am meticulous enough to keep my code in line, should I be able to utilize those memory just fine?

Comment: If the stack element you're trying to access isn't mapped into the process's current address space, what exactly do you expect to happen? other than a signal? and why?

Comment: P.S Just to clarify, I was not doing this randomly.  What I initially intended to do was overflow the return address of an user-defined function, and make EIP pointing to some malicious shell code, but unfortunately I found out that  it appeared I could not perform buffer overflow on my machine, and could not figure out why.

Comment: Your current problem is not the stack protection; if you compiled it like you said you did, stack protection IS disabled. What currently happens is that EIP points to an invalid address (one that isn't mapped into the process's current address space, as EJP said). If you'd try to run it with proper shellcode, your exploit should work.

Comment: @glenjoker - I find it very *fortunate* that it is hard to insert malicious code.  :-)  Even if I knew how to make it work, I would be reluctant to make that info public.

Comment: @SwedishOwlSerpent - I see your point. I'll go though my code again to see if I have miscalculated the place of the return address. Thanks for your help

Comment: And thanks to everyone who has replied to my thread of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GNU Debug to find the distance, here is a tutorial http://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf

Comment: Sure, I've been thinking about learning how to use gdb for a while, thanks for the link. As for the additional 8 bytes offset from the return address, I am not very familiar with this, but I think Ubuntu is x86 architecture?

Comment: I meant that Ubuntu is x86 architecture, but N32 and N64 are for MIPS according to that wikipedia page

Comment: you are right, if you are using 64-bit ubuntu then your processor is x64. i do not know then why there is this 8 byte gap however when you read tutorials on buffer-overflows there is stated that the return-address can not be exactly determined (when not using gdb) and you should use NOPs and trial-and-error, see http://www-rn.informatik.uni-bremen.de/lehre/itsec/itsec05-2u.pdf, p. 4 (is in german)

Comment: this tutorial is nice: https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~bmiller/cis459/2007s/readings/buff-overflow.html

Comment: to finish this, buffer[ ] is the buffer that overflows, however str[ ] has to be filled until the return address is overwritten. where the return address is located can either be determined by GDB or by trial-and-error...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and profuse thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.